# External CSS Stylesheet not loading

Tags: html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <link rel="css" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>
            <strong>C</strong>ascading
            <strong>S</strong>tyle
            <strong>S</strong>heets
        </p>
    </body>
</html>


p {
    color: blue;
    text-decoration: underline;
    }
strong {
    color:red;
    }
body {
    background: aqua;
    }
```

For some reason this won't load. I ran it through CSS and HTML validators, but I use developer tools and it shows no css stylesheets attached, and my (very basic) formatting is not being applied. I looked at a few other questions and nothing fixed this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `rel="stylesheet"` instead of `rel="css"`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css"/>
```

And if your file path is correct then it must load css, simple as that

Answer (score 4):

Try with this format

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="yourCss.css">
```

Read more at http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_link_rel.asp

Answer (score 3):

Let me if it works

> HTML DOC

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
           //Change rel to stylesheet and it done
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css"/>
        </head>
        <body>
            <p>
                <strong>C</strong>ascading
                <strong>S</strong>tyle
                <strong>S</strong>heets
            </p>
        </body>
    </html>
```

> Stylesheet.css

```
  p {
        color: blue;
        text-decoration: underline;
        }
    strong {
        color:red;
        }
    body {
        background: aqua;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
```

To load external css you must include a reference to the css file inside the **link tag**

[Check live demo](http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_howto_external)